# I pointed EIP to the ESP address and put my shellcode in ESP successfully, but I get a SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: binary, gdb, buffer-overflow, nomachine-nx

Before creating this post I tried and read all the previous Q&A but they do not seem to answer my exact question.

I am also referring to the guide on below link, but I am missing something crucial.

https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2009/07/19/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-1-stack-based-overflows/

Here's what I did so far, there is a buffer overflow in the program and I figured out the offset (using msf tools) for EIP and EBP. It's 267 and 263 respectively.

The program requires me to input "42" as the first input, then it prompts for another question where in I can give A*264 to overflow the buffer. Below is the payload I am using, it includes the string 42, a bunch of NOP sleds (263 precisely), preserving EBP value, ESP memory offset (0xbffff480) to be overwritten on EIP and my shellcode.

http://pastebin.com/g4kK2pC8

After I execute the above, in gdb when I see the values of ESP and EIP are the same i.e. 0xbffff480

This is where I have put my shellcode and EIP is pointing this. But, why doesn't my shellcode get executed? It fails with "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."

I am not sure where I am going wrong. So my idea of pointing/overwriting EIP to ESP value is wrong? Or something to do with my shellcode? How can I write a simple shellcode/payload that would print something for instance or just check if execution is happening?

**Update:**

I used the checksec.sh script to check if the binary has NX enabled and below is the output I got.

```
RELRO           STACK CANARY      NX            PIE             RPATH      RUNPATH      FILE
Partial RELRO   No canary found   NX enabled    No PIE          No RPATH   No RUNPATH   output
```

Does this mean I cannot run my shellcode? I just have to focus on evading/bypassing NX? - Does the Partial RELRO make any difference?

Comment: Does the binary have DEP or ASLR enabled?

Comment: Also, are you sure you have a working shellcode?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @drum. How can I check if these are enabled? Also, how can I test my shellcode, I used msfpayload to generate one and I assumed it works.

`code`msfpayload linux/x86/exec CMD=/bin/sh R | msfencode -b \x00\xff -t c > shellcode

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I just noticed your checksec output, so you'll need to compile with:

```
gcc -z execstack
```

It's difficult without looking at the memory in the debugger, but the problem *may* be that your shellcode needs more space to decode itself.

The encoded shellcode (I see you're doing this with msfencode), will need to be decoded in place before the intended payload (in your case linux/x86/exec) can be run. The decoding process will typically overwrite a portion of the memory space before it, so if there is not enough writable space for this to happen, problems can occur (i.e. segmentation faults). So in the below example, we would see the decoder overwriting memory above 0x00000008 (appologies if this looks nothing like your buffer as I can't see pastebin from where I am).

```
0x0400001C 41 41 41 41 
0x04000018 41 41 41 41
0x04000014 41 41 41 41
0x04000010 41 41 41 41
0x0400000C 55 55 55 55 <-- Return address
0x04000008 12 34 56 78 <-- Start of shellcode
0x04000004 90 12 34 56 
0x04000000 78 90 12 34
```

Try prepending your shellcode with an interrupt ("\xCC") and then step through the shellcode in GDB to see what it happening.

You could then try adding in some NOP's ("\x90") between your return address and the start of your shellcode. I would recommend starting with 32.

Let me know if this looks like the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow these steps in order to create a working exploit :
1- determine the offset using pattern_create/offset.rb
2- overwrite eip with anything such as "BBBB"
3- put some NOPs after the tip
4- put the shellcode after the NOPs
5- search for a command in the program such as "jmp esp" or "call esp"(you can read this article :https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2009/07/23/writing-buffer-overflow-exploits-a-quick-and-basic-tutorial-part-2/ )
6- overwrite the eip with the address of the command 
7- boom ! shellcode executed